# javascript/jquery only affects first element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this html code for a search form and i would like to use jquery to edit the url to

```js
let searchform, searchurl, i; searchurl = window.location.href;

searchform = document.querySelector("form.dgwt-wcas-search-form");
searchform.action = searchform.action + "index.php";
```

```html
<form class="dgwt-wcas-search-form" role="search" action="https://www.myurl.com/" method="get">
        <div class="dgwt-wcas-sf-wrapp">
                        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="dgwt-wcas-search-input-3">Products search</label>
            <input id="dgwt-wcas-search-input-3" type="search" class="dgwt-wcas-search-input" name="s" value="" placeholder="Search for products..." autocomplete="off">
            <div class="dgwt-wcas-preloader" style="right: 81.2812px;"></div>
                            <button type="submit" aria-label="Search" class="dgwt-wcas-search-submit">Search</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product">
            <input type="hidden" name="dgwt_wcas" value="1">
</div>
</form>

<form class="dgwt-wcas-search-form" role="search" action="https://www.myurl.com/" method="get">
        <div class="dgwt-wcas-sf-wrapp">
                        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="dgwt-wcas-search-input-3">Products search</label>
            <input id="dgwt-wcas-search-input-3" type="search" class="dgwt-wcas-search-input" name="s" value="" placeholder="Search for products..." autocomplete="off">
            <div class="dgwt-wcas-preloader" style="right: 81.2812px;"></div>
                            <button type="submit" aria-label="Search" class="dgwt-wcas-search-submit">Search</button>       
            <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product">
            <input type="hidden" name="dgwt_wcas" value="1">
                    </div>
    </form>
```

The script only changes the first url in searchbox into https://www.myurl.com/index.php
but the second searchbox will not get the script to run.

I would like two search forms to change the url from https://www.myurl.com/ to https://www.myurl.com/index.php

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: *i would like to use jquery* - you're not currently using jquery, are you sure you want a jquery solution?  Or did you mix jquery/javascript?   Otherwise it's trivial in jquery, using [attr](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function)

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're using a wrong document function to query, you should have used "querySelectorAll" instead of "querySelector" so that it returns all items that match the query.

After that, you'll need to loop over the array of forms and set action for each form just like you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let searchform, searchurl, i;
searchurl = window.location.href;

searchform = document.querySelector("form.dgwt-wcas-search-form");
searchform.action = searchform.action + "index.php";
```

```html
<form class="dgwt-wcas-search-form" role="search" action="https://www.myurl.com/" method="get">
  <div class="dgwt-wcas-sf-wrapp">
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="dgwt-wcas-search-input-3">Products search</label>
    <input id="dgwt-wcas-search-input-3" type="search" class="dgwt-wcas-search-input" name="s" value="" placeholder="Search for products..." autocomplete="off">
    <div class="dgwt-wcas-preloader" style="right: 81.2812px;"></div>
    <button type="submit" aria-label="Search" class="dgwt-wcas-search-submit">Search</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product">
    <input type="hidden" name="dgwt_wcas" value="1">
  </div>
</form>

<form class="dgwt-wcas-search-form" role="search" action="https://www.myurl.com/" method="get">
  <div class="dgwt-wcas-sf-wrapp">
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="dgwt-wcas-search-input-3">Products search</label>
    <input id="dgwt-wcas-search-input-3" type="search" class="dgwt-wcas-search-input" name="s" value="" placeholder="Search for products..." autocomplete="off">
    <div class="dgwt-wcas-preloader" style="right: 81.2812px;"></div>
    <button type="submit" aria-label="Search" class="dgwt-wcas-search-submit">Search</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product">
    <input type="hidden" name="dgwt_wcas" value="1">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: While code-only answers may actually solve the problem they lack the important values of stackoverflow which is to help ppl to improve their own skills leading to solving their problems by themselves. Therefore please add some further explanation on what the code does and how it solves the problem.